# Stuck with docker command not found on first installation of docker-machine

Tags: docker, shell, docker-machine

I'm getting into Docker and as my Catalina system doesn't support virtualisation I'm using `docker-machine` using `VirtualBox`.
I followed the installation guide at https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/ and got to the point that I can create a new machine with `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default` command and it appears when linking machines with `docker-machine ls`.
Then

> To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: docker-machine env default

so I run it and the command is

> Run this command to configure your shell:
> eval $(docker-machine env default)

run that too so as Docker's docs continue I should be able to run Docker commands like the suggested `docker run busybox echo hello world` but I get `zsh: command not found: docker` error message.

The exact steps I used following the Docker docs are:

```
0 Install Docker Desktop 

1 enable writing on the /usr/local/bin folder for user

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin  

2 install Docker-Machine

base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0 &&
  curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine &&
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine

3 install Xcode CLi..manually from dev account

4 Install Home Brew

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"


5 Install wget ( Using Brew)

brew install wget

6 Install bash completion scripts

base=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/machine/v0.16.0
for i in docker-machine-prompt.bash docker-machine-wrapper.bash docker-machine.bash
do
  sudo wget "$base/contrib/completion/bash/${i}" -P /etc/bash_completion.d
done

7 enable the docker-machine shell promp

  1: vim ~/.bashrc

   2: i

  3: Pasted this:

PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__docker_machine_ps1)]\$ '

4: press esc
5: press :
6: type wq! and press enter


Install VirtualBox, ExtensionPack and SDK


https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Done!
```

I thought that the problem was that I added `PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__docker_machine_ps1)]\$ '` to the `.bashrc` file instead that to `.zshrc` as I'm on Catalina so I corrected it and quitted Terminal. Reopened it and now terminal shows `[\u@\h \W$(__docker_machine_ps1)]\$` as instead of `vinnytwice@Vinnys-iMac ~ %`(is this looking right?).
I re run the `docker-machine ls` and listed correctly the previously created virtual machine so I connected again the shell to it with `eval $(docker-machine env default)`but when running docker command `docker run busybox echo hello world` still same `zsh: command not found: docker` error ..
Can you see why is not running docker commands?
As always many thanks

Answer (score 1):

ok..finally found the problem..as the error message states.. there is no Docker CLI installed.. I thought that installing Docker desktop would also install it as the docker-machine installation guide stated to install that, but I guess it meant for virtualisation capable machines..not my case.. So installed it with brew command `brew install docker` and it's al there working now.
Also the `PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__docker_machine_ps1)]\$ '` setting goes indeed in the `.bashrc` file not the `.zshrc`.
Hope it helps other starting out..